# Is there any phone shake event I can catch in HTML 5 and Windows 8 Phone SDK?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am planning to make a app using Windows 8 Phone SDK, the app I am planning to make is to play audio on phone shake.

As I am already well versed with HTML 5 I am planning to use HTML 5 Project template for this.

So my question is : Is there any phone shake event I can catch and play audio files in HTML 5 ?

Please share your thoughts on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no event for detecting a shake in HTML on WP8.

The nearest thing you could do is detect it in code (using this [shake gesture library](http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2011/02/22/windows-phone-shake-gestures-library.aspx)) and then when the shake is detected have it call a function in the HTML/JS on the page loaded in the web browser to play the sound.